# Avoid generator splitter to produce None values

Tags: python, python-3.x, split, generator

I have a thousands of IDs extracted from a CSV file (now it is a generator of IDs) to iterate and process those IDs.

To optimise the code, I have grouped those IDs in the batches and processing an entire batch at a time.

Following code partition-ate the generator in the batch size of n.

```
from itertools import zip_longest
def grouper(n, iterable):
    """ Grouping of iterable with n objects
       Attributes
       :n No. of values in a group
       :iterable/string to be iterated
       :return group of string/iterator values
    "grouper(3, 'abcdefg') --> ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g',None, None)"
    """
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*n)
```

e.g.:

```
>>>acc_ids = ['ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47', 'ID54', 'ID58']
#--As an iterator
>>>id_generator = (i for i in acc_ids)
>>>batches = grouper(7, id_generator)
>>>batches
<itertools.zip_longest object at 0x7f3beb3313b8>
#This iterator is much similar to the below list and notice padded `None`(s) at the end of last batch:
#[('ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47'), ('ID54', 'ID58', None, None, None, None, None)]
```

Here is the problem, To remove padded `None` values from the iterator I'm using `filter`

```
for batch in batches:
    batch = list(filter(None, batch))
```

This filter is removing `None` values from the list. Since I'm thinking, instead of adding an extra filter, can we prevent producing padded `None` values while splitting the generator...

Queries:

- Is there any other approach to split big generator to produce batches
  without adding None/Null values at the end of last batch.
  OR
- Can we change above function `grouper` to suppress producing padded None values?

Comment: *"But this filter is returning me a list"*, in Python 3, it doesn't return a list, a `filter` object is returned.

Comment: Docs of `filter` in Python 3 "Return an iterator yielding those items of iterable ..."

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard : Sorry about that looks like I was converting it to a list to fire a HTTP API call,  I will update the question I just want to remove padded None  values. and have to avoid using filter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
def grouper(n, iterable):
    iter_ = iter(iterbale)
    while True:
        res = tuple(next(iter_) for _ in range(n))
        if not res:
            return
        yield res


acc_ids = ['ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47', 'ID54', 'ID58']
id_generator = iter(acc_ids)
batches = grouper(7, id_generator)
print(list(batches))
```

Output:

```
[('ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47'), ('ID54', 'ID58')]
```

Comment: Instead of `raise StopIteration` it would be better to `return` (yeah, just return nothing). The `raise StopIteration` is deprecated for (probably good) reasons.

Comment: @MSeifert Yes, looks a bit nicer. Changed. Thanks.

Comment: I would put the `iter` call inside the function so is not need to call it with a explicit iterator

Comment: @Copperfield Good suggestion. Modified accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use an external library that already includes such a function:

- [`iteration_utilities.grouper`](https://iteration-utilities.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/grouper.html):

  ```
  >>> from iteration_utilities import grouper
  >>> list(grouper(acc_ids, 7))
  [('ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47'), ('ID54', 'ID58')]
  ```
- [`more-itertools.chunked`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#more_itertools.chunked):

  ```
  >>> from more_itertools import chunked
  >>> list(chunked(acc_ids, 7))
  [['ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47'], ['ID54', 'ID58']]
  ```
- [`pytoolz.partition_all`](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.partition_all) or `cytoolz.partition_all`:

  ```
  >>> from toolz import partition_all
  >>> list(partition_all(7, acc_ids))
  [('ID21', 'ID24', 'ID38', 'ID40', 'ID42', 'ID43', 'ID47'), ('ID54', 'ID58')]
  ```

These libraries all have liberal licenses (Apache, MIT and BSD) so even if you don't want the dependency you might just reuse their code (you might need to include their license in your code though, see their licenses for further details).